# Test if a column exist in index sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have this `sqlserver query` to generate a query text that I can use to update all columns types from `nvarchar/ nchar` to `varchar/char`.

```
SELECT
    AlterSql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' ALTER COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME, ' ', SUBSTRING(DATA_TYPE, 2, LEN(DATA_TYPE)), '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ') ', CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'YES' THEN 'NULL' WHEN 'NO' THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'ERROR' END, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), 'GO')
  , *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar')
```

The issue is when I running it, an error displayed that it can't cast the columns exists in indexs.

So I should test if the column exist in index or no, then I delete the index, covert and recreate my index.

How can I modify my script to do it ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you trying to convert every single column of nchar or nvarchar to its counterpart? You are limiting the data that can be stored in your system and potentially going to lose information.

Comment: Freeing up space is NOT a valid reason to limit the data that can be stored. Unless you are more than 100% certain that you will NEVER EVER EVER receive a value outside the ASCII character set this is just plain and simply a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check `CONSTRAINT` exit or not, if so then drop it as following

```
IF  EXISTS (
               SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = 
               OBJECT_ID(N'[CONSTRAINTNAME]') AND type = 'D'
            )
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[_COMPANY] DROP CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINTNAME]
END
```

Then use your statement

```
SELECT
    AlterSql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' ALTER COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME, ' ', SUBSTRING(DATA_TYPE, 2, LEN(DATA_TYPE)), '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ') ', CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'YES' THEN 'NULL' WHEN 'NO' THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'ERROR' END, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), 'GO')
  , *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar')
```

Comment: I think the point is they want to have a query that finds the constraints as they don't know the names of all of them ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure sp_helpindex does, what you want, you can exec it into table in memory and proceed

```
declare @t table
(
 index_name sysname collate database_default NOT NULL,
 index_description nvarchar(512)    ,
 index_keys sysname
)
insert into @t exec sp_helpIndex 'items'
--do whatever with this data here 
select * from @t
```

And i join to Sean Lange question: why you need it?

Comment: To free a space in my database, because nvrchar and nchar takes more a space